# Error while parsing json from IBM watson using python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I am trying to parse out a JSON download using python and here is the download that I have:

```
{  
   "document_tone":{  
      "tone_categories":[  
         {  
            "tones":[  
               {  
                  "score":0.044115,
                  "tone_id":"anger",
                  "tone_name":"Anger"
               },
               {  
                  "score":0.005631,
                  "tone_id":"disgust",
                  "tone_name":"Disgust"
               },
               {  
                  "score":0.013157,
                  "tone_id":"fear",
                  "tone_name":"Fear"
               },
               {  
                  "score":1.0,
                  "tone_id":"joy",
                  "tone_name":"Joy"
               },
               {  
                  "score":0.058781,
                  "tone_id":"sadness",
                  "tone_name":"Sadness"
               }
            ],
            "category_id":"emotion_tone",
            "category_name":"Emotion Tone"
         },
         {  
            "tones":[  
               {  
                  "score":0.0,
                  "tone_id":"analytical",
                  "tone_name":"Analytical"
               },
               {  
                  "score":0.0,
                  "tone_id":"confident",
                  "tone_name":"Confident"
               },
               {  
                  "score":0.0,
                  "tone_id":"tentative",
                  "tone_name":"Tentative"
               }
            ],
            "category_id":"language_tone",
            "category_name":"Language Tone"
         },
         {  
            "tones":[  
               {  
                  "score":0.0,
                  "tone_id":"openness_big5",
                  "tone_name":"Openness"
               },
               {  
                  "score":0.571,
                  "tone_id":"conscientiousness_big5",
                  "tone_name":"Conscientiousness"
               },
               {  
                  "score":0.936,
                  "tone_id":"extraversion_big5",
                  "tone_name":"Extraversion"
               },
               {  
                  "score":0.978,
                  "tone_id":"agreeableness_big5",
                  "tone_name":"Agreeableness"
               },
               {  
                  "score":0.975,
                  "tone_id":"emotional_range_big5",
                  "tone_name":"Emotional Range"
               }
            ],
            "category_id":"social_tone",
            "category_name":"Social Tone"
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

I am trying to parse out `'tone_name'` and `'score'` from the above file and I am using following code:

```
import urllib
import json
url = urllib.urlopen('https://watson-api-explorer.mybluemix.net/tone-analyzer/api/v3/tone?version=2016-05-19&text=I%20am%20happy') 
data = json.load(url)
for item in data['document_tone']:
    print item["tone_name"]
```

I keep running into error that tone_name not defined.

Comment: Your code does not correspond to the structure of the JSON you're parsing. `data['document_tone']` is a dictionary, but `'tone_name'` is a key in dictionaries much further down the structure.

Comment: Does my answer help? If not, please tell me why so I can edit it.

Answer (score 0):

As [jonrsharpe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3001761/jonrsharpe) said in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37502848/error-while-parsing-json-from-ibm-watson-using-python#comment62500719_37502848):

> `data['document_tone']` is a dictionary, but `'tone_name'` is a key in dictionaries much further down the structure.

You need to access the dictionary that `tone_name` is in. If I am understanding the JSON correctly, `tone_name` is a key within `tones`, within `tone_categories`, within `document_tone`. You would then want to change your code to go to that level, like so:

```
for item in data['document_tone']['tone_categories']:
    # item is an anonymous dictionary
    for thing in item[tones]:
        print(thing['tone_name'])
```

The reason more than one for is needed is because of the mix of lists and dictionaries in the file. `'tone_categories` is a list of dictionaries, so it accesses each one of those. Then, it iterates through the list `tones`, which is in each one and full of more dictionaries. Those dictionaries are the ones that contain `'tone_name'`, so it prints the value of `'tone_name'`.

If this does not work, let me know. I was unable to test it since I could not get the rest of the code to work on my computer.

Answer (score 0):

You are incorrectly walking the structure. The root node has a single `document_tone` key, the value of which only has the `tone_categories` key. Each of the categories has a list of tones and it's name. Here is how you would print it out (adjust as needed):

```
for cat in data['document_tone']['tone_categories']:
    print('Category:', cat['category_name'])
    for tone in cat['tones']:
        print('-', tone['tone_name'])
```

The result of this is:

```
Category: Emotion Tone
- Anger
- Disgust
- Fear
- Joy
- Sadness
Category: Language Tone
- Analytical
- Confident
- Tentative
Category: Social Tone
- Openness
- Conscientiousness
- Extraversion
- Agreeableness
- Emotional Range
```

Comment: Glad I could help. If the problem is completely resolved, please accept the answer (click checkmark below the score).